# Installing Magento 2 Data Migration Tool

Tags: git, composer-php

I'm trying to install Magento 2 Data Migration Tool on a cPanel account via SSH. So far everything went well till the stage of installing the migration tool with the command line below. I verified and can confirm that Composer was installed. But Whenever I enter the command line below I get an error message, `"-bash: composer: command not found".`

Below is the command line I'm using

```
composer.phar config repositories.magento
composer https://repo.magento.com
composer require /vendor/magento/data-migration-tool:2.0.2
```

Magento instructions here http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/migration-tool-install.html

Thanks in advance for your help!!!

Comment: looks like composer is not on your path. Where is it installed? Try 'which composer' to find out. Then you can either add it to your path or run it from the location given by 'which composer'

Comment: Why are you running `composer.phar` correctly the first time and the wrong command the next 2 times?

Comment: Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Actually, Composer is installed globally on the server so that every cPanel account can use.

I used "which composer" and it didn't show any info, so I tried, "which composer.phar" and it showed "/usr/bin/composer.phar". So I assumed I have to add that path to the command line, but using that path "/usr/bin/composer.phar" instead of just "composer.phar" also didn't not work. Example below...

Comment: /usr/bin/composer.phar config repositories.magento 
/usr/bin/composer.phar https://repo.magento.com
/usr/bin/composer.phar require magento/data-migration-tool:2.0.2

Answer (score 0):

Please execute this command from your Magento root directory to install data migration tool,

```
- composer update
- composer config repositories.data-migration-tool git https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool
- composer require magento/data-migration-tool:2.2.2
```

Replace 2.2.2 with your Magento 2 version.

I hope this will help you.